# Dynamic CRM InvalidSecurity CRM8

Tags: xml, soap, dynamics-crm-2011

I am connecting Dynamics CRM but getting error "an error occurred when verifying security for the message"

URL: org.crm8.dynamics.com

URN: crmapac:dynamics.com

Getting this error:

http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/soap/faulturn:uuid:{3990AF7E-8D80-FD8F-9A1B-29141D6A0E0C}s:Sendera:InvalidSecurityAn error occurred when verifying security for the message.

Please suggest me what i need to change

Comment: Its Resolved :

Should use "crmind:dynamics.com" for CRM8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Its Resolved I used "crmind:dynamics.com" for CRM8

**Dynamics CRM Online regions:**
North America (crm)
South America (crm2)
Canada (crm3)
EMEA (crm4)
APAC (crm5)
Australia (crm6)
Japan (crm7)
India (crm8)
North America 2-for Government (crm9)

**URN List :**
          "CRM2.DYNAMICS.COM" : "crmsam:dynamics.com"  
          "CRM4.DYNAMICS.COM" : "crmemea:dynamics.com"
          "CRM5.DYNAMICS.COM" : "crmapac:dynamics.com"
          "CRM6.DYNAMICS.COM" : "crmoce:dynamics.com"
          "CRM7.DYNAMICS.COM" : "crmjpn:dynamics.com"
          "CRM9.DYNAMICS.COM" : "crmgcc:dynamics.com"
          "CRM8.DYNAMICS.COM" : "crmind:dynamics.com"
          "CRM.DYNAMICS.COM"  : "crmna:dynamics.com"
```

Comment: Hi, we have a project integrated with MSCRM referring to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602979(v=crm.5).aspx this worked well for crm instances which were based on crm5. Now we are trying to sync to instance with crm8 but i keep getting org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: An error occurred when verifying security for the message. In the soap request urn:crmna:dynamics.com shouldnt it be dynamic. Also from what you have posted as answer here it is suggested different http://scaleablesolutions.com/connecting-android-apps-to-dynamics-crm-using-soap-endpoint/